# C# WinForm takes times for Initializecomponent()

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, telerik, initializecomponent

I am working on C# application where i am using "Telerik" controls to design the form. I have 5 tabs in Ribbon control having around 15 controls in each tab. The main problem arise when i run the code. It takes some time to load all the controls, it shows grey screen until controls loaded completely. The problem is with `InitializeComponent()` which is taking time. So is there any solution(s) which i can use so that my designer can load fast and i can avoid slow load of designer. I can't upload full code. But i can give some idea how i have designed.

```
RadRibbonBar myRibbon;//ribbon control
this.myRibbon.CommandTabs.AddRange(new Telerik.WinControls.RadItem[] {
            this.rbnTab1,
            this.rbnTab2,
            this.rbnTab3,
            this.rbnTab4,
            this.rbnTab5});//add tabs

 this.rbnTab1.Items.AddRange(new Telerik.WinControls.RadItem[] {
            this.rbngroup1,
            this.rbngroup2,
            this.rbngroup3,
            this.rbngroup4});//add groups in tab

 this.rbngroup1.Items.AddRange(new Telerik.WinControls.RadItem[] {
            this.rbnBtn1,
            this.rbnBtn2,
            this.rbnBtn3,
            this.rbnBtn4});//add button in each group

myRibbon.ThemeName = "Office2013Light";
```

Each tab with 5 groups, each group with 4 button

Apart from this 15 buttons in StartMenu, around 10 controls in QuickAccessToolBar

NOTE: I am adding ribbon control in SplitContainer, and when i add ribbon from designer it takes entire screen to load slow whereas if i load ribbon at the end of window_load event than first it shows remaining controls and than its usual time to show ribbon.

Comment: Interesting, I am wondering if it would speed it up to move the "this.myRibbon.CommandTabs.AddRange" to below the multiple "rbngroup1.Items.AddRange" calls.  Also, is "SuspendLayout" called before these?  I'm wondering if suspending layout might help.  Also are you doing any custom layout code, or was this auto generated?

Comment: No worries on the upset, just look at my history, I'm always getting point loss for losing my shit :-) OK, so it's a Telerik issue of some sort... try removing from designer and doing it programmatically?  That way you can put timers in etc and see what exactly is taking long.  Have you tried telerik's forums?  They are usually pretty good.

Comment: I tried doing it programmatically but it doesn't help. And i tried in telerik's forum and i explained whole scenario to them, they sent me their sample code for same scenario, but their code is not showing any lag. Also there are some more things i am doing apart from just adding controls. I am setting properties of controls (like image, height, width, autosize, bounds, visiblity, enable - disable and so on)

Comment: OK, let's be logical then.  Try it without any of your properties being set (like image, height, width, auto size, bounds, visibility, enable - disable and so on) , let's try to figure out exactly what is the slow part(the "image" comment makes me sit up a bit)

Comment: I tried by removing images from all the controls, removing theme and autosize. But the result is the same :( may be some positions i need to change, like adding some controls after some controls or adding some controls at the end and so on.

Comment: And when i removed `MyContainter.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.MyRibbon);` the events are getting called fast. and when i add same line, events (constructor end to window load) getting called slow. It means `MyContainter.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.MyRibbon);` is culprit. But how do i solve that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas, I would open a ticket with Telerik.

Comment: @Trey, did you got any suggestions for issue?

Comment: Sorry but I am out of ideas, without your source and toolkits, I am just guessing.  Again, try contacting Telerik support.  Good luck!